# AcLayers.dll currupt or damage error when launching Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, launch

When i am launching unity3d, pop-up comes with AcLayers.dll currupt or damage as image below:

[image]

please help if anyone have faced this error and solved it.

Comment: This is not a Unity3D specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `AcLayers.dll` is part of Windows, which means something broke your OS.

Try to restore your Windows 8 Installation like this:

1. Press the Windows Key and X on your desktop
2. Select *Command Prompt (Administrator)* in the menu
3. In the Command Prompt window type the following, and press Enter:

   > sfc /scannow

SFC scan will make Windows replace corrupt or missing system files on your computer.